# why does typescript not allow circular references in generics?

Tags: typescript, types

here the examples where the type directly references itself in its definition, but when abstracted via a generic it completely fails.

```
type a = { val: a }; // <-- doesn't care about circular references!

type record<T> = { val: T };

type b = record<b>; // <-- doesn't work!

type func<T> = (arg: T) => void;

type c = func<c>; // <-- doesn't work!

type d = (arg: d) => void; // <-- works!?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [microsoft/TypeScript#41164](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41164) for a canonical answer to this question.

TypeScript *does* allow circular references in [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [*interfaces*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) and [generic *classes*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-classes), since interfaces and class instances have statically known property/member/method *key*s and so any circularity happens in "safe" places like property *value*s or method parameters or return type.

```
interface Interface<T> { val: T }
type X = Interface<X> // okay

class Class<T> { method(arg: T): void { } }
type Y = Class<Y> // okay
```

But for generic [*type aliases*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) there is no such guarantee.  Type aliases can have any structure that any anonymous type can have, so the potential circularity is not constrained to recursive tree-like objects:

```
type Safe<T> = { val: T };
type Unsafe<T> = T | { val: string };
```

When the compiler instantiates a generic type, it *defers* its evaluation; it does not immediately try to fully calculate the resulting type.  All it sees is the form:

```
type WouldBeSafe = Safe<WouldBeSafe>; 
type WouldBeUnsafe = Unsafe<WouldBeUnsafe>;
```

Both of those look the same to the compiler... `type X = SomeGenericTypeAlias<X>`.  It cannot "see" that `WouldBeSafe` would be okay:

```
//type WouldBeSafe = { val: WouldBeSafe }; // would be okay
```

while `WouldBeUnsafe` would be a problem:

```
//type WouldBeUnsafe = WouldBeUnsafe | { val: string }; // would be error
```

Since it cannot see the difference, and because at least some usages would be illegally circular, it just prohibits all of them.

---

So, what can you do?  This is one of those cases where I'd suggest using `interface` instead of `type` when you can.  You can rewrite your `record` type (changing it to `MyRecord` for naming convention reasons) as an `interface` and everything will work:

```
interface MyRecord<T> { val: T };
type B = MyRecord<B>; // okay
```

You can even rewrite your `func` type (changing it to `Func` for naming convention reasons again) as an `interface` by changing the [function type expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions) syntax into a [call signature syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures):

```
interface Func<T> { (arg: T): void }
type C = Func<C>; // okay
```

Of course there are situations where you can't do that directly, such as the built-in [`Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype):

```
type Darn = Record<string, Darn>; // error
```

and you can't rewrite the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) `Record` as an `interface`.  And indeed, it would be unsafe to try to make the keys circular, like `type NoGood = Record<NoGood, string>`.  If you only want to do `Record<string, T>` for generic `T`, you *can* rewrite *that* as an `interface`:

```
interface Dictionary<T> extends Record<string, T> { };
type Works = Dictionary<Works>;
```

So there's quite often a way to use an `interface` instead of `type` to allow you to express "safe" recursive types.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-OdDkgoRFHIIaLaABo-fBIJacXj4rK8GJneBUNBwHJIA4OFzYAAPOCQaw6INikMtcNMYwdQ29DYKHRCW0ptMZrNfOuaRZAA)

Comment: thanks! this is cool and helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Let's dissect these scenario's one by one.

#### Scenario 1

```
type a = { val: a }; // <-- doesn't care about circular references!
```

It's interesting this is allowed. I don't see how you could be able to construct an instance that would satisfy this type:

```
const A: a = {
  val: {
    val: {
      // It will always error out at the most inner node.
    }
  }
}
```

#### Scenario 2

```
type record<T> = { val: T };
```

This is not a circular reference and can be satisfied like this:

```
const B: record<string> = {
  val: "test"
}
```

### Scenario 3

```
type b = record<b>; // <-- doesn't work!
```

It makes sense to me that this doesn't work. Just like in Scenario 1, there would be no way to construct an instance that satisfies this constraint.

### Scenario 4

```
type func<T> = (arg: T) => void;
```

This is not a circular reference and can be satisfied like this:

```
const C: func<string> = (arg: string) => {}
```

### Scenario 5

```
type c = func<c>; // <-- doesn't work!
```

It makes sense to me that this doesn't work. Just like in Scenario 1, there would be no way to construct an instance that satisfies this constraint.

### Scenario 6

```
type d = (arg: d) => void; // <-- works!?
```

I can actually write a function to satisfy this constraint, but I am not sure what it's getting me:

```
const D: d = (arg) => {}
D(D)
```

Comment: I believe 6 represents a self-composable function; I've used something similar, except with `(arg?: d) => void`, _i.e._ by making the argument optional.